# TypeScript Type: String matching pattern

Tags: typescript

I am querying a system API (Linux' `DBus` API) that expects 3 `string`s:

- `service`
- `path`
- `name`

So I could write the signature of the TypeScript methods that calls the interface like so:

```
getInterface(service: string, path: string, name: string): DBusInterface;
```

But I know , `service`, `path` and `name` each follow specific string patterns:

- `service` = `/^org\.bluez/`
- `path` = `/(\/[a-zA-Z]*)+/`
- `name` = `/([a-zA-Z]+\.)+/`

*(Regex not 100% correct, but here for comprehensibility)*

I am wondering if it is possible to type guard the 3 parameters to match these patterns, like

```
type ServiceName: /^org\.bluez/
```

Comment: Thank you Asaf! Can you post this as an answer, then I can accept this as solved! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently as of **11/2019** this is not possible, there is an open suggestion for this for a while now that you can keep track of here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579

You can read the comments and maybe find something useful